# Request header field x-user-session is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: c#, wcf, cors

I am trying to do a CORS call to a WCF service endpoint hosted on IIS7.5.

I have configured custom headers in IIS. My configuration looks like below

```
<customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="x-user-session,origin, content-type, accept" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
```

When I do a POST request I get following error message
"Request header field x-user-session is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"

If I remove my custom header from the call and run it, everything works fine.

Also if I do a GET call with custom header then also API works correctly.

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   success: function(d) { console.log(d) },
   timeout: 9000,
   url: "http://api.myserver.com/Services/v2/CreditCard.svc/update_cc_detail",
   data: JSON.stringify({"card_id":    1234,"expire_month":"11","expire_year":"2020","full_name":"Demo Account", "number":"4111111111111111","is_primary":true}),
   xhrFields: { withCredentials: true}, 
  headers: { x-user-session':  "B23680D0B8CB5AFED9F624271F1DFAE5052085755AEDDEFDA3834EF16115BCDDC6319BD79FDCCB1E199BB6CC4D0C6FBC9F30242A723BA9C0DFB8BCA3F31F4C7302B1A37EE0A20C42E8AFD45FAB85282FCB62C0B4EC62329BD8573FEBAEBC6E8269FFBF57C7D57E6EF880E396F266E7AD841797792619AD3F1C27A5AE" },
crossDomain: true,
   contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

### UPDATES

Following is a link to the FireBug log
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7333130

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably the issue is that the `OPTIONS` request is returning an error (404 or 405). This would explain why `GET` works properly (it doesn't always require preflight request) while `POST` don't (it always require preflight).

Usually the easiest solution for WCF services hosted on IIS is to enable all methods through `WebInvokeAttribute`:

```
[WebInvoke(Medthod="*")]
...
```

Sometimes the IIS is blocking the `OPTION` request with its default `OPTIONSVerbHandler`. You can remove this handler through your web.config:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

In worst case scenario (when the `OPTIONS` is not blocked by IIS but can't be handled by WCF) you can set your own handler. In such scenario first you need to a simple class like the one below in an assembly:

```
namespace CustomHandlers
{
    public class CORSOPTIONSVerbHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Response.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            else
                context.Response.StatusCode = 405;

            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

The new handler can be added in web.config like this:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
    <add name="CORSOPTIONSVerbHandler" verb="OPTIONS" path="*" type="CustomHandlers.CORSOPTIONSVerbHandler, CustomHandlers"/>
</handlers>
```

Of course you need to adjust the assembly, namespace and class name properly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My CORS call are working. I am able to handle OPTIONS without any problem. My problem starts when I send a custom header in the request. As I said earlier if I dont include a custom header in request everything works without trouble. Once I include a custom header and do a POST call I get following error    "Request header field x-user-session is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari The bahaviour which you describe doesn't prove that preflight request is handled properly as it is not required for GET - to make sure about that I would suggest making network traffic dump (with Fiddler, FireBug or some other browser development tool) and adding it to the question so we can analyze it. Also can you provide an information is this behaviour consistent through all the browsers (for example some versions of Chrome have an issue in which they expect the Access-Control-Allow-* headers only on preflight request and cancel the actual request if it have them as well).

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari Well the error message is correct, the response to `OPTIONS` request contains following value for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`: `origin, content-type, accept`. The question is why... Can you recheck your config file?

Comment: Thanks I will check again

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your web.config

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
```

It usually happens because of cross-origin requests

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with service stack, and to properly make your service to answer to the OPTIONS request, you need to explicitly put by yourself the headers. Maybe in WCF is not necessary, but I would try.

Using tpeczek's code:

```
namespace CustomHandlers
{
    public class CORSOPTIONSVerbHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Response.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers" ,"x-user-session,origin, content-type, accept");
            else
                context.Response.StatusCode = 405;

            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

I've not tried the code, it may not run, but I hope the idea is clear :)